# MYSQL Joins is not returning required records

Tags: mysql

I need a query that will retrive leave requests by joining two tables, staff & leaverequest. The request could be approved or requested. There are approvedby & employeeid that identify the approver & the requester,the record for which can be found in the staff table as employeeid. If the request is not approved the approvedby record will be null.

```
SELECT s.letterRequestId 
     , s.businessId letterRequestType
     , r.approvedBy 
     , DATE(s.approvedDate) approvedDate
     , s.requestedBy 
     , DATE(s.requestedDate) requestedDate
     , s.employeeId
     , r.status 
     , r.documentPath 
     , CONCAT(s.firstName, "  ", s.lastName ) Name
     , CONCAT(a.firstName, "  ", a.lastName ) `Approver Name`
  FROM Leave_Requests r
  join Employee s
    on e.employeeId = r.employeeId 
  join Employee a
    on a.employeeId = r.approvedBy;
```

The above sql is returning only approved leaves.

Thanks

Comment: See `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Have you tried using an OR `join Employee s
    on (s.employeeId = r.employeeId OR s.emplyeeId = r.approvedBy);` or just use an UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT s.letterRequestId 
     , s.businessId letterRequestType
     , r.approvedBy 
     , DATE(s.approvedDate) approvedDate
     , s.requestedBy 
     , DATE(s.requestedDate) requestedDate
     , s.employeeId
     , r.status 
     , r.documentPath 
     , CONCAT(s.firstName, "  ", s.lastName ) Name
     , CONCAT(a.firstName, "  ", a.lastName ) `Approver Name`
  FROM Leave_Requests r
  LEFT join Employee s
    on e.employeeId = r.employeeId 
  LEFT join Employee a
    on a.employeeId = r.approvedBy;
```

Comment: Welcome @AyubAhmed.

Answer (score -1):

You have an implicit `inner join` with the `approver` table (join on `requests.approvedBy`) which filters out rows with `null` values on `approvedBy`.

You should replace this with a `left join` and properly handle null values when `concat`ing approver name:

```
SELECT s.letterRequestId 
     , s.businessId letterRequestType
     , r.approvedBy 
     , DATE(s.approvedDate) approvedDate
     , s.requestedBy 
     , DATE(s.requestedDate) requestedDate
     , s.employeeId
     , r.status 
     , r.documentPath 
     , CONCAT(s.firstName, "  ", s.lastName ) Name
     , CONCAT(a.firstName, "  ", a.lastName ) `Approver Name`
  FROM Leave_Requests r
  join Employee s
    on e.employeeId = r.employeeId 
  LEFT JOIN Employee a
    on a.employeeId = r.approvedBy;
```